# What is the difference between if( pointer == NULL) and if(!pointer)?

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the difference in between using:

```
if( pointer == NULL)
```

And

```
if(!pointer)
```

I am concerned with the differences between the two in respect to the following points:
 1. Are they different for the compiler? If yes, then how?
 2. Which of the two is the recommended coding style for general use and why?
 3. Can you please explain how NULL is "seen" by the compiler.

Edit: For the sake of simplicity let pointer be of type int *.

Comment: It all depends on the type of `pointer`. Can we assume it is something like `int *` and not some class that does operator overloading?

Comment: What type is `pointer`?

Comment: What is the value of `NULL`?

Comment: Regarding #3, `NULL` is an implementation-defined macro.  Typically its value will either be `0` or `nullptr`.  Explicitly using `nullptr` is generally considered better than using the `NULL` macro.

Comment: If `pointer` is a type that has overridden `operator!` and/or `operator==` then they are potentially very different as they'll call different functions.

Comment: @0x5453 NULL will not be nullptr;  the reason for this is that NULL can be used for integer comparisons; while nullptr is strictly pointer comparisons.

Comment: Emitted code by an optimizing compiler is probably the same. It is practically a matter of style and readability. C++11 prefers `nullptr` to `NULL`

Comment: I would recommend that question 2 be removed since this is off topic as opinion based.  The other 2 however are fair.

Comment: @UKMonkey It doesn't necessarily need to be removed. It can be reworded to "what are the (technical) advantages and disadvantages of each style". I don't think it would be too broad.

Comment: @nwp sure - I'll rephrase to "as it stands" :P

Comment: @UKMonkey `NULL can be used for integer comparisons` No. NULL cannot be used for integer comparisons. It can be of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: @user2079303 of course it can.  You can do `if (myInt == NULL)` and expect it to compile.  You can not however do `if (myint == null_ptr)` which is WHY it was introduced in the first place.

Comment: @UKMonkey it can't. You can do `myInt == NULL` and you can *hope* for it to compile and it might. But it is not guaranteed to. `nullptr` wasn't introduced so that you couldn't compare it with integers. It was introduced to disambiguate overload resolution unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @user2079303 So people were passing in NULL as a pointer and it was picking the integer overload?  So ... people were defining NULL to be 0?  In that case, why not change the standard to say that NULL must be nullptr?  Because it's a breaking change; as it was previously required to be an integer (and that's not changed).

Comment: @UKMonkey It has changed. The standards committee isn't above allowing breaking changes. For what it's worth, requiring `NULL` to be an integer in C++ (until C++11, since when it hasn't been required) was a mistake in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Are they different for the compiler? If yes, then how?

If `pointer` indeed has a pointer type, then there is no difference at all for the compiler.

> 2. Which of the two is the recommended coding style for general use and why?

There probably are recommendations either way.

A possible advantage of using `!pointer` is that there is no opportunity to mistype `pointer = NULL`, which has very different meaning, but is well-formed. Another advantage is that is requires less typing.

> 3. Can you please explain how NULL is "seen" by the compiler.

As specified in the standard, `NULL` is an implementation defined macro, which expands to a null pointer constant.

Comment: If you mistype `if (pointer = NULL)` and your compiler is not warning you about it you should change the warning flags until it does.

Comment: Before those compiler warning were implemented, `NULL == pointer` was recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `pointer` is a pointer type, `if (pointer == NULL)` is anachronistic and poor C++ since the the null pointer value in C++ is `nullptr` in C++ with *type* `nullptr_t`.

`if (!pointer)` is the *much* preferred idiom.

Comment: There are people who say implicit bool conversions are terrible and `pointer == nullptr` is the much preferred idiom. Without any statistics or polls to back it up I wouldn't assume my opinion is the generally accepted one.

Comment: [ES.87: Don't add redundant == or != to conditions](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-if)

Comment: On the other Hand: Rule 5-3-1 of Misra-C++08 says: "Each operand of the ! operator, the logical && or the logical || operators shall have type bool." So `if ( !ptr)` is not compliant according to the rule

Answer (score 1):

1. They are both a comparison to 0; one is just explicit.  You can work out the difference to the compiler by looking at the assembly produced.
2. This is a matter of opinion and therefore off topic.
3. NULL is a macro that should equate to 0.  For this reason it's considered bad practice to use when comparing to pointers since the nullptr has an implicit conversion to pointer types, thus preventing it being used with integers; while NULL has no such conversion and thus can be compared to integers.